# Macros with 0, 1 or 2 arguments

Tags: macros, arguments

Is it possible to build a macro accepting 0, 1 or 2 arguments ? Why ? I want to have the following functionalities.

1. `\exercice` will print `Exercice` alone.
2. `\exercice{2}` will print `Exercice (2 pts)`.
3. `\exercice{2}{Source:...}` will print `Exercice (2 pts) [Source: ...]`.

Comment: Check the xparse documentation. It offers various ways to implement optional arguments.

Comment: Yes you can, although the usual way is to use optional arguments `\exercise`,  `\exercise[2]` and `\exercise[2][Source: ...]`. With `xparse` package you can do `\NewDocumentCommand\exercise{oo}{Exercise\IfValueT{#1}{ (#1 pts)}\IfValueT{#2}{ [#2]}}` which defines `\exercise[..][..]`; and if you substitute `oo` for `gg` in the defintion you will define what you asked for: `\exercise{..}{..}`.

Comment: I like the `\NewDocumentCommand`. I did not know it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better: use a key-value syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\exercice}{O{}}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { projetmbc/ex } { #1 }
  \par\vspace{\topsep}\noindent Exercice
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l_projetembc_ex_pts_tl
   { ~(\tl_use:N \l_projetembc_ex_pts_tl\nobreakspace pts) }
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l_projetembc_ex_note_tl
   { ~[\tl_use:N \l_projetembc_ex_note_tl] }
  \group_end:
  \quad\ignorespaces
 }
\keys_define:nn { projetmbc/ex }
 {
  points .tl_set:N = \l_projetembc_ex_pts_tl ,
  note   .tl_set:N = \l_projetembc_ex_note_tl ,
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\exercice Text

\exercice[points=2] Text

\exercice[note=Source: folklore] Text

\exercice[points=4,note=Source: folklore] Text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This API is very good. Thanks for this even if I think that in my case there is no really necessity to indicate the options. But regarding the generality of your solution, I have marked to be an accepted answer.